# Custom Register form not working

Tags: html, web2py

Hie folks..... When I click on submit button of the CUSTOM REGISTRATION form..... it redirects to the same page...... ?? No idea what this is about......
Controller: default.py

```
def register():
        form=auth.register()
        form.add_button('Cancel', URL('register'))
        return dict(form=form)
```

View: register.html
Please take the little pain to open this link to view the html file.... I am unable to post the exact html code in here... problem with syntax..
http://pastebin.com/bPQu2DX3

```
 print form.errors -> Storage {}
```

```
 print form.accepts(request.vars,session) -> false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx folks .. Finally got the answer....
I was not putting all the fields in custom form..
the fields that one doesn't require and is validated as not null also needs to be mentioned in custom form as hidden attributes otherwise whole of the form won't get accepted.

Comment: No need to add hidden fields to the form. A better approach is to set the readable and writable attributes of those fields to False (e.g., `db.auth_user.some_field.readable = db.auth_user.some_field.writable = False`) before creating the form. Also, that isn't the only problem -- you still cannot call `form.accepts()` after calling `auth.register()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicated line `form=auth.register()`
You return `dict(late=late, form=form)`  but *late* is never used in your controller...

I think you should simplify your controller :

```
def register():
    form=auth.register()
    form.add_button('Cancel', URL('register'))
    return dict(form=form)
```

Comment: Thanx for that... hav changed the code.... those were small typos.. refer to my previous comments on Anothony's answer for more clarification....

Answer (score 0):

First, your first two lines are useless, as the third line simply overwrites the "form" variable with a completely new object. Second, auth.register() already handles the form processing, so you cannot subsequently call form.accepts(). If you want to control the flash messages, use the auth.messages object to set them.

Comment: @anthony.... Those were the typos added duplicated the form to check for the working without the custom thing... now it's okay... and late was a global variable in my controller.... I removed those.... please have a look now...

Comment: Your code is still wrong. You cannot call form.accepts() after auth.register() (the .register() method already calls .accepts() itself -- processing the form twice won't work).

Comment: See http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control#Settings-and-messages.